# Configuring Bind9 Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

I Just installed a new server and this is my scenario:

1. Public (valid, static) IP acquired
2. Domain name acquired
3. BIND9 installed, maybe wrong configured
4. Apache2 installed, running
5. Server Name: ICARUS
6. Server OS: Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS

Everything is running fine, I can access my default page through IP.

Now, I can't get the domain name to resolve to my IP and I have some questions.

What are the values to put in my registrar's dns server fields for my domain? It's something related to my server name?

I have two IP addresses provided for my ISP.. are those the IPs my registrar need to register my priate name server as icarus.domain.com ? what about the other required name ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registrar requires 2 name servers to be listed.  You can locate them on the same machine (if the machine is assigned two IPs, you can use different names for each IP, e.g., icarus.domain.com and daedalus.domain.com), but this creates a single point of failure with regard to DNS services, so it's generally frowned upon.

If you run your own name servers, which you are apparently intending to do, you can use a service like http://backupdns.com/ as a secondary.  In that case, you'd have one name server as icarus.domain.com and the other one ns01.backupdns.com.  If you're not familiar with running a name server, you may also consider just using a service like DNSimple or Amazon's Route53.  In that case, you do not necessarily need to run BIND on your own box.

Comment: I actually don't care too much where is my domain name resolving, since it points to my IP.

Comment: Is anyone going to use your server besides you?  If it's just you, and you don't care that much about outages, go ahead with using the second IP address you have for that box as the other nameserver for your registrar.

Comment: the goal right now is to use this server to serve a single domain, but in future maybe more. Just to get this clear, I can use the IP addresses provided for my ISP as DNS servers?

Comment: Yes, you can.  The requirement for two is for redundancy.  If you don't have a high priority for that, you can run BIND on one box, listening on two different IP addresses.  It's generally not a recommended configuration, but it's not prohibited.

Comment: Ok, I am a little confused, sorry. I only have one valid IP address, and the ISP provides 2 more that for the DNS1 and DNS2, which allow me to access internet. Are you talking about those secondary IP or I need to get a second valid IP ?

Comment: After many years of running BIND on four different servers and several secondaries/slaves, running it only on one seems like an invitation for disaster. Unless, of course, the disaster will not cost you anything.

Comment: assuming the disaster will be not critical and the recovery will be fast. I can do what I need with only one physical server with a single public IP?

Comment: Yes you can! Make sure your registrar will allow you to provide only one dns server.

Comment: The registrars I've seen require two or more name servers, though it's possible I didn't look very hard to try to use only one name server.  If you're required to enter a second name server, get a second IP address for your machine from your ISP, and set up your BIND to listen on both IPs.  Then list both IPs with your registrar as two different name servers.

Comment: I just contacted my registrar and asked if this is possible to do with only one IP.. waiting for an answer.

Comment: Ok, the guy just tell me is possible and asked another dns name, so i give him another name. So, what I need to do with the second DNS name in BIND?

Comment: Your first IP is named icarus.  Give the second IP a name (e.g., daedalus, if that name isn't assigned), and list both icarus and daedalus with the registrar as the name servers for the domain.  Make sure that BIND is listening on both icarus and daedalus)

Comment: done! icarus.domain.com and destiny.domain.com are now registered by the registrar and there's a propagation time of about 24h. Next step, the BIND9 configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have installed BIND then I guess you will do your own DNS serving. Then your registrar will need YOUR server's IP address as the DNS server. Of course things will work only after you properly set up BIND. We usually provide two (or more) DNS servers, different of course, so you will need another DNS server to provide you some backup.

Comment: This means that I need two physical servers? with a different public IP each ?